# iTunes personal music library is empty

Tags: macos, itunes, osx-el-capitan

I have an iTunes library with thousands of songs in it. I haven't opened iTunes for a while, but today I wanted to import a new cd, started iTunes and without thinking I imported the cd. I needed to set the bitrate, which was rather strange, but I did so, and the cd was imported.

Then I opened my personal music library, which was totally empty except for this cd. I opened the Finder and all music was still there. In the settings I checked if iTunes used the right folder, which it did.

My Macboo is rather old, and I had to disable Spotlight because it slowed down the machine too much.

I wonder where the new cd is stored.

How can I restore the old library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [If you don't see your content after you update iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203225)

1. Quit iTunes.
2. Go to the iTunes folder that contains the iTunes library files:
3. Mac: From the menu bar at the top of your computer screen, choose Go > Home. Open the Music folder, then open the iTunes folder.
4. Windows: Navigate to \Users\username\Music\iTunes.
5. Drag the iTunes Library.itl file to your Desktop.
6. In the iTunes folder, open the Previous iTunes Libraries folder.
7. Find the file named iTunes Library YYYY-MM-DD where YYYY-MM-DD is the date you updated iTunes (Year-Month-Day).
8. Copy this file to the iTunes folder (the enclosing folder).
9. Rename the copied file iTunes Library.
10. Open iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my girlfriend a few months back. Being an IT specialist, I had no idea what could have happened.

However, I ran a few things to find out what was using all her space (since I noticed her disk space was running high).

It turns out that the iPhone backups had been saved for about 4 years, 100GB of it. After deleting these, the library magically appeared. It might be tied to this.

I would suggest looking at your disk usage on your laptop and see if clearing out a few large, no longer needed files will return it back to life.

There is no way to know what happened to your files unless you just do some simple trial-and-error steps.

Also, run a disk check on your hard drive. If it's more than 4 years old, it's prone to dying anytime soon.